# Regular expressions for Windows based file path and UNC path

Tags: c#, regex, powershell

I need to validate the file path/folder structure for reg expressions in PowerShell. Please find below the examples.

```
c:\\scan\document\(*)  
c:\\scan\document\word.doc  
\\share\network\(*)  
\\share\network\note.txt
```

Note: Need to validate for the folder path and file with any extensions as well. Please help.

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z]\:|\\\\[\w\.]+\\[\w.$]+)\\(?:[\w]+\\)*\w([\w.])+$
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? More detail, please.

Comment: Why no simply use `Test-Path` with `-IsValid` parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Why no simply use Test-Path with -IsValid parameter?*

Adding to davor's suggestion...here is a link to some examples:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730955.aspx